# Use MySQL JOIN instead of a query in PHP While loop

Tags: php, mysql, loops, optimization, join

I'm trying to remove a mysql query from inside a PHP while loop and use a JOIN instead.

I have a query

```
SELECT *, 
SUM(CASE WHEN posmonth like '2013%' THEN ext ELSE NULL END) AS year2013, 
SUM(CASE WHEN posmonth like '2012%' THEN ext ELSE NULL END) AS year2012, 
SUM(CASE WHEN posmonth like '2011%' THEN ext ELSE NULL END) AS year2011, 
SUM(CASE WHEN posmonth like '2010%' THEN ext ELSE NULL END) AS year2010 
FROM combined c 
LEFT JOIN customermaster cm ON c.alias=cm.customerkey 
WHERE cm.company LIKE 'A%' 
GROUP BY customerkey 
ORDER BY cm.company ASC 
LIMIT 0, 50
```

Then with these results fetch data from another table "areamaster"
using:

```
    <?php 
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
   while ($r = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
    $alias = $r->alias;
    $company = $r->company;
    $a = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT area FROM areamaster WHERE areakey='$alias' LIMIT 1");
    while ($t = mysqli_fetch_object($a)) { $aliasdisplay = $t->area; }
    //Instead of this ^^ USE JOIN IN ORIGINAL QUERY
    ?>
    <tr>
         <td><?php print (substr($company,0,20)); ?></td>
         <td><?php print (strtoupper($r->location)); ?></td>
         <td><?php print $aliasdisplay; ?></td>
         <td>$<?php print number_format($r->$year4V,2,".",","); ?></td>
         <td>$<?php print number_format($r->$year3V,2,".",","); ?></td>
         <td>$<?php print number_format($r->$year2V,2,".",","); ?></td>
         <td>$<?php print number_format($r->$year1V,2,".",","); ?></td>
   </tr>
   <?php
   }
   mysqli_free_result($result);
    ?>
```

Two mysql tables structures:

```
areamaster:
     areakey: Primary
     area: What I want displayed

combined:
     id:primary
     posmonth: for totaling ext by Year
     alias: compare to areamaster.areakey and get "areamaster.area"
     location: 
     ext: being totaled by SUM
```

IF anyone could help write the JOIN I'd appreciate it.

Also, if there is any way of further optimizing this query, please let me know.

Comment: Try `YEAR(posmonth)` instead of the string matching you're doing. doing the string version forces mysql to reformat its internal date/time format into a string, instead of directly poking at the year bits inside the field's native structure. Of course, that assumes posmonth is a native date/time field.

Comment: Just took care of that, Thanks Marc

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN posmonth like '2013%' THEN ext ELSE NULL END) AS year2013, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN posmonth like '2012%' THEN ext ELSE NULL END) AS year2012, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN posmonth like '2011%' THEN ext ELSE NULL END) AS year2011, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN posmonth like '2010%' THEN ext ELSE NULL END) AS year2010 
FROM combined c 
LEFT JOIN customermaster cm ON c.alias=cm.customerkey 
LEFT JOIN `areamaster` as a ON a.area = c.alias
WHERE cm.company LIKE 'A%' 
GROUP BY customerkey 
ORDER BY cm.company ASC 
LIMIT 0, 50
```

This is edited try again

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that edit gave me an SQL syntax error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM areamaster ON areakey = c.alias WHERE cm.company LIKE 'A%' GROUP BY cust' at line 9

Comment: Raheel, I figured out my problem, I was joining from the wrong spot, thanks for everything though.